# Retrieve the folders of dashboards/reports with vscode package.xml

Tags: vs-code, package.xml, folder, reports-folder, retrieve

I want to register a report folder using the package.xml in VScode and transfer the folders.

I entered the following source code in the package.xml, and when I performed a retrieve in the terminal, an error occurred and the folder was not registered in the reports column.

```
<types>
        <members>ReportFolder_xxx1</members>
        <members>ReportFolder_xxx1/ReportFolder_xxx2</members>
        <name>ReportFolder</name>
 </types>
```

The error message is:

```
unpackaged/package.xml Entity of type 'Report' named 'ReportFolder_xxx1/ReportFolder_xxx2' cannot be found
```

I think this is because there are no reports in the folder yet. I plan to create the reports on a different day, but I want to transfer the folder structure first.
Is there a way to register the folder even if there are no reports in it?

Comment: _but I want to transfer the folder structure first_ : why, what are you trying to accomplish? See [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)